# How to know that no operation is running on ConcurrentHashMap or in Idle state in JAVA?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrenthashmap

I have a situation like, whenever my ConcurrentHashMap updates I need to clear an existing file and write the entire data into the File again. So every time I update clearing the file and writing the data again into the file causes high latency. So I am thinking that whenever my hashmap is in Idle state, like if no updating operation is going on then I will write the entire data into the file, else I will wait until the hashmap is idle.

Basically, I will be deleting Strings continuously from the Map. So everytime I delete a String from the HashMap writing to the file is a very costly operation. So is there a way to know that no deletion operation is going on the ConcurrentHashMap?

Comment: you can use a simple shared flag setting it to true just before the start of the delete operation & setting it to false just after delete operation & keep checking for the value of this flag in a different thread, whenever you find the shared flag to be false, go in for your file operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So is there a way to know that no deletion operation is going on the ConcurrentHashMap?

Short answer: no there isn't a way.

But even if there wasn't you would still get into problems.  For example, suppose that new updates arrived immediately after you started clearing / writing.

---

I think the solution is to use two maps and a queue.

- When an update request happens:

  1. perform the update on the concurrent hashmap
  2. add the request to the queue
- In a background thread:

  1. pull requests from the queue, and perform updates on the second (shadow) hashmap
  2. periodically or based on some other criteria, cease pulling requests and flush the shadow hashmap to the file.

The primary hashmap is always updated quickly, and is always up to date.  Operations updating and using the primary hashmap do not get (significantly) blocked.

The queue provides request buffering while the shadow hashmap is being written.

The second hashmap is only accessed by one thread, so it doesn't need to be concurrent.  Therefore it will be faster.

The state of the file will typically be a little behind the primary hashmap.  But that is inevitable.  The only way to avoid that is to block updates to the primary map ... which is what you are trying to avoid.

---

Another way to approach this would be to make writing to the file faster.  I suspect that the reason it is slow is because your current design requires you to clear and rewrite the file each time.  Another approach would be to write only the *changes* to the file.  This means you may have more work to do on restart ... assuming the purpose of the file is to record the map state so that you can restart.

Comment: I suspect simply serializing the hash map to a file is the fastest way to write it.  And it's much better to save the map to a *new* file, then rename the new file over the old one.  That way there's always a valid copy on disk.

Comment: That depends on the size of the file and the rate of changes.  There will be a break-even point where storing increments becomes faster than storing snapshots.

Comment: Given that good SSDs can be bought for less than $100, that break-even point is going to be an awfully huge file.  It's a lot cheaper, faster, and much less bug-prone to solve any performance issue saving this map to disk with faster hardware than it is to try writing code.

Comment: Not that large.  Serializing and persisting a map consumes CPU time as well as physical I/O time.  In fact, if you are repeatedly writing / rewriting the same file on a Linux system, performance probably is not limited by disk output speed.  The OS does not hold up your application while the bytes are written to the disk or SSD.  It does the writes to the device asynchronously.

Comment: Even if the OP isn't a high-priced employee, the labor cost to code an incremental-save solution is probably at least a few thousand dollars, with bugs and an O&M tail still left to pay for.  That's a *lot* of fast hardware.

Comment: It is rarely that simple.  For instance, there is a good chance that he is developing stuff to run on a public or private cloud platform.  You can't just walk into the data centre and plug a $100 SSD into a compute node.   There is a good chance there will be multiple instances of his software running on multiple computers.  And so on.  Faster hardware *may* solve the problem more economically, or it may not be economical (even including labor) or it might not solve the problem at all.  As I said above, physical I/O speed is not necessarily the bottleneck.  If it isn't, then SSDs won't help.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you would need to make use of encapsulation by wrapping the ConcurrentHashMap in a class and possibly have add/remove methods with a Queue. Look at the [java.util.concurrent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package for other options.

The Idea would be to use a `Queue`. Every access to the `Map` would go by calling the add/remove from the wrapper and add that to the queue. Then there would be an infinite Thread loop consuming the queue. While doing that you can check if the queue is empty and do the file persisting.

Comment: *check if the queue is empty and do the file persisting.*  That could be a TOCTOU bug waiting to happen - and what happens if the queue is never found to be empty?  The hash map won't ever be saved to disk.